# install jdk 6 or higher on a mac osx 10

Tags: java, android, macos

If I run `javac -version` on my mac (osx 10.11.3), I get this output

```
javac 1.8.0_73
```

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio) android dev page, I need JDK 6 or higher. I downloaded jdk 7 and 8 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and clicked on the dmg but I'm getting the same output `javac 1.8.0_73` when running `javac -version`

Question: how can I install jdk 6 or higher on a mac?

Answer (score 2):

Versions of the JDK have a naming convention of 1.x, 1.x.0_##, etc. The "x" is the product version number. This means that your return of "javac 1.8.0_73" means you already have JDK 8u73.